# Move primary tabs to the shortcuts bar

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs, routes, users

I am using drupal7 and the admin menu overlay (in seven). And I'm always apalled by the primary tabs appearing in view mode. They are messing up the layout for the editors / admins, and they're usually not in style with either the site design or the overlay design.

I was just wondering .. is there a pretty way to move the primary tabs ('edit' et al) to the admin overlay shortcuts bar - 'if the overlay is visible and you are in view mode'

Perhaps there are two answers:

1. remove the primary tabs from the content, if the overlay is visible and you are in view mode
2. add the primary tabs to the shortcuts bar,    if you are in view mode

Any hints ?

*-pike

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet

Comment: Huh ? If by "extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable" you mean all users of Drupal 7, then yes. The overlay admin, the seven theme, the primary tabs, are all standard in 7. Did I phrase the question wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu module.

It has an option to move the tabs into the admin menu bar.
Set it by going to the admin menu settings page (admin/config/administration/admin_menu) and checking the "Move local tasks into menu" option.

For users gien access to the admin menu, you should remove access to the drupal toolbar module, or they will have 2 toolbars.

You could even disable to toolbar module and just use admin menu.

If you want to keep using the toolbar module instead of the admin menu module, you can remove the tabs from the page.tpl.php file in your theme and then print them elsewhere.

I don't know off the top of my head how you would go about doing that though.

Comment: excellent, brilliant, exactly what i meant.